# How do I perform a recursive checkout using ClearCase?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I want to check out all files in all subdirectories of a specified folder.

(And it is painful to do this using the GUI, because there is no recursive checkout option).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Beware: ClearCase is File-centric, not repository centric (like SVN or CVS).

That means it is rarely a good solution to checkout all files (and it can be fairly long with ClearCase ;) )

That being said, the question is perfectly legitimate and I would like to point out another way:

open a `cleartool` session in the 'specified folder':

```
c:\MyFolder> cleartool
cleartool> co -c "Reason for massive checkout" .../*
```

does the trick too. But as the aku's answer, it does checkout *everything*: files and directories... and you may most *not need* to checkout directories!

```
cleartool find somedir -type f -exec "cleartool checkout -c \"Reason for massive checkout\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

would only checkout files...

Now the problem is to checkin everything that has changed. It is problematic since often *not everything* has changed, and CleaCase will trigger an error message when trying to check in  an identical file. Meaning you will need 2 commands:

```
ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "ci -nc \"%n\"\n" | ct
ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "unco -rm %n\n" | ct
```

(with '`ct` being '`cleartool`' : type '`doskey ct=cleartool $*`' on Windows to set that alias)

Note that `ct ci -nc` will check-in with the comment used for the checkout stage.
So it is *not* a checkin without a comment (like the `-nc` option -- or "no comment" -- could make believe).

Answer (score 8):

```
cleartool find somedir -exec "cleartool checkout -nc \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Also an article "[ClearCase: The ten best scripts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html)" might be helpful

Comment: If you are using Linux, replace %CLEARCASE_PN% with $CLEARCASE_PN

Comment: @Peewhy Good point. `CLEARCASE_PN` (for PathName) or `CLEARCASE_XPN` are both environment variables set by clearcase scripts (`cleartool find` for instance). The Windows syntax (`%...%`) or Unix syntax (`$...`) is in effect for them.