# ClearCase: How can I check-in, check-out multiple files?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

Let's assume I'm checking-out and checking-in multiple files for my tasks. Can I make check-in, check-out operations for multiple files at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have documented a recursive checkout in 2008 with "[How do I perform a recursive checkout using ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119595/6309)".

But if you are taking about a specific group of files, not all in the same folders, the [`cleartool checkout`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm) command itself can accept multiple files:

```
cleartool checkout  pname ...
                    ^^^^^^^^^
                    Path names of one or more elements to be checked out. 
                    space-separated
```

Same for [`cleartool checkin`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkin.htm), although you can find and list all checked out files, and check them in, as I mentioned in "[Recursive checkin using Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974016/6309)": this time, the files can be in different folders without issue.

Comment: Ok, I was searching for the command that you shared. So, I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check-in, checkout multiple files recursively or trying to perform this operation within the same folder?

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122520