# How to sort file path names in hierarchy basis?

Tags: sorting, tree, recursive-datastructures

I want to sort out file names in hierarchy basis.

Let say I have below list of folders:

```
D:Movies\Hollywood\Comedy\adultcomedy
D:Movies\Hollywood\Comedy\horrorcomedy
D:Movies\Hollywood\Romantic\ adult
D:Movies\Bollywood\Action\comedy
D:Movies\Bollywood
D:Movies\Hollywood\Comedy
D:Movies\Hollywood
D:Movies
D:Movies\Hollywood\Romantic
```

I want to sort them in single line, which means the last children should be sorted first, and grand grand parent should be sorted as last Child

(I.e):

1. Movies — Grand parent
2. Hollywood — child of Movies
3. Bollywood — child of movies / Sibiling of Hollywood
4. Comedy — child of hollywood / grand child of Movies
5. adultcomedy— child of Comedy / descendant for Movies
6. horrorcomedy — child of Comedy /sibiling of adultcomedy
7. Romantic — child of Hollywood / Sibiling of Comedy and same for others

Here by I wanted to sort this as descendant from grand parent.
(i.e) —> 4 th level is extreme grand child in this structure, which means it should sort:

- As first element `adultcomedy`
- then it’s sibiling `horrorcomedy`
- then 4th Level of grand children `adult` from `Romantic`
- then `comedy` from `Action`
- then `Comedy` which is child of Hollywood and parent of `adultcomedy,horrorcomedy` and
- then `Romantic`
- then `Hollywood`
- then `Bollywood`
- finally `Movies`.

```
D:Movies\Hollywood\Comedy\adultcomedy D:Movies\Hollywood\Comedy\horrorcomedy D:Movies\Hollywood\Romantic\ adult
D:Movies\Bollywood\Action\comedy D:Movies\Hollywood\Comedy D:Movies\Hollywood\Romantic D:Movies\Hollywood D:Movies\Bollywood
D:Movies
```

Here I can’t use array,. Only I can use tree strucutre to solve this problem.,

What I have tried.,

- tried to count length but it’s failed due to dynamic path change
- checked whether another path has substring of another path

But none of the algorithms are working.

Sample code to understand the structure:

```
<forall _="ChildrenWithKey" name="fDir" in="vtList" param="ElementDir" >
 <!-- here vtList has element paths as children &  all the path has a Key:ElementDir name- alias name, so that we can use this tree anywhere -->

<!-- lets consider the list of paths above mentioned all has a Key:ElementDir -->
```

Comment: No specific programming language?

Comment: It’s proprietary language,. Which has combination of oops and xml, and there we can store the Elements and parameters in node and tree ., we have conditional loops where we can set nodes as conditional operators

Comment: OK, why does Bollywood not come *before* Hollywood? Is there a rule for this?

Comment: There is no rule Like that, this is just an example folders I have written in my own., in real we will be having views and vobs ( I.e) version control system elements

Comment: So if I propose an algorithm where Bollywood would come before Hollywood, it would be OK?

Comment: Yeah it’s not a problem,. Only thing I want is the higher level file should be sorted first,. Which means **adultcomedy** should be first with complete path and **Movies** should be last as that is having only one level

Comment: Is the input given as a tree structure? Or as an array of strings (like you provided at the top)? It a tree, can you provide the tree structure for the sample data?

Comment: It’s a tree structure.,

Comment: Sample input : inputTree : child1- path1 ,. Child2-path2, child3- Path3 and so on

Comment: Hmm... that is not so clear to me... Can you edit your question and provide the concrete tree structure for the sample data?

Comment: Sure! One moment

Comment: @trincot hope you understand the structure now ?!

Comment: Oh no! Not an image. Don't you have an exact, programmatic, structure? Like JSON or whatever, but in a programming language's notation? And: with the sample data all reflected in it ("Hollywood", "Bollywoord", "Romantic", ... the whole shebang!)?

Comment: Actually those elements like “Hollywood” ,”Bollywood” all folders path will be stored as a string in ~> inputTree <~ so I will be taking the tree and take all children of that tree and perform this operation,. In such a way only I will write code

Comment: If you wish I can show you the original code and structure but I don’t know how to add that in Stackoverflow ., it’s little proprietary as I said earlier., because of that only I can’t able to get help from internet 

Comment: I guess you can't get help then, indeed. I don't understand how the structure could be proprietary. I can understand *data* or an *algorithm* is, but not structure with sample data. Anyway, that's the end of this question then for me.

Comment: let me paste a piece of code here which can access and structure the data, Please see whether you understand, so that I can still have my last hope

Comment: Instead of code that accesses the data, is there no programmatic description of the data? Like JSON?

Comment: its kind of Xml data , its called Linked Modular Object Oriented Xml , and a combination of Xml & XsD , I have mentioned structure of the code and and added commands for your understanding

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I don't see the tree data.

Comment: Thanks for your time Gentle man, I really appreciate your intent to help.. Thank you so much once again.. Let me try crack my brain